# Which device Docker Container writing to?

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, disk

I am trying to throttle the disk I/O of a Docker container using the blkio controller (without destroying the container), but I am unsure how to find out which device to run the throttling on.

The Docker container is running Mongo. Running a df -h inside the bash of the container gives the following:

```
root@82e7bdc56db0:/# df -h
Filesystem                                                                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-524400-916a3c171357c4f0349e0145e34e7faf60720c66f9a68badcc09d05397190c64   10G  379M  9.7G   4% /
tmpfs                                                                                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1                                                                                         32G  3.2G   27G  11% /data/db
shm                                                                                                64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
```

Is there a way to find out which device to limit on the host machine? Thanks!

$docker info

```
Containers: 9
 Running: 9
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 6
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-524400-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 1.694 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 30.31 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 3.994 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.143 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.110 (2015-10-30)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-38-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.675 GiB
Name: ip-172-31-6-72
ID: 4RCS:IMKM:A5ZT:H5IA:6B4B:M3IG:XGWK:2223:UAZX:GHNA:FUST:E5XC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

df -h on the host machine:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           377M  6.1M  371M   2% /run
/dev/xvda1       32G  3.2G   27G  11% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           377M     0  377M   0% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: could you do a `docker info` and a `df -h` on the host machine ?

Comment: Done. I feel like there might be an obvious answer here but it would be helpful if you explain what is happening under the hood with docker

Comment: With this version of Docker you should be able to use this : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/block-io-bandwidth-blkio-constraint

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this but this is for 'docker run', whereas I would like to change this dynamically using 'docker update', which is currently unsupported for disk i/o

Comment: You can use --blkio-weight with `docker update`

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointer, this should do the trick for what I want to do. I am still curious about the original question of which device you would have to specify when using the blkio controller directly

Comment: In fact all your Docker layers are stored in the loop file : `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data` So I think it would be difficult to manually create blkio rules